# Use Baire’s theorem to show that the set of transitive configurations is dense in $X$.

Tags: general-topology, compactness, baire-category

Let $X :=$ {$0, 1$}$^\mathbb N$. Let $x = x_1x_2 · · · ∈ X$ be a configuration and $w =
w_1w_2 · · · w_n ∈$ {$0, 1$}$^∗$ be a word. We say that $w$ occurs in $x$ at position $k$ if $x_kx_{k+1}· · · x_{k+n−1} = w_1w_2 · · · w_n$. For instance, $w := 1011$ occurs in the configuration
$x := 01101101100001010001···$ at positions $3$ and $6$ but not at position $1$. Let $C_k(w)$ denote the set of all configurations in which $w$ occurs at position $k$, and note that $C_1(w) = C(w)$ is simply the (standard) cylinder set with base $w$.
A configuration $x ∈ X$ is said to be transitive if every word $w ∈$ {$0, 1$}$^∗$ occurs in $x$ at some position.

$(i)$ Provide an example of a transitive configuration in $X$.

$(ii)$ Use Baire’s theorem to show that the set of transitive configurations is dense in $X$.

$(iii)$ Provide a direct construction based on part $(i)$ of a dense set of transitive configurations.

$(iv)$ Show that in every transitive configuration $x$, every word $w$ occurs at infinitely many different positions.

My attempt:

$(i)$ example: For $n = 4$, let $w = 0110$ and $x = 01101101110101101... $ is it correct?

$(ii)$ Baire's Theorem: if $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space, then the intersection of any countable collection of dense open sets is dense; i.e., if $A_1,A_2,...A_n \subset X$ open and dense, then $\cap_{n=1}^∞ A_n$ is dense and in particular non-empty.

Here, $X=${$0,1$}$^\mathbb N$ is compact and Hausdorff, and $C(w)$ is the cylinder set which is a basis, and hence is open by definition of basis. How do I proceed from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot produce a transitive configuration by looking only at words of length $4$, let alone at just one of those words. A transitive configuration must contain at least one instance of **every** word in $\{0,1\}^*$. Probably the easiest way to produce such a configuration is to concatenate the non-empty words in [shortlex order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortlex_order):

$$0\color{red}100\color{red}{01}10\color{red}{11}000\color{red}{001}010\color{red}{011}100\color{red}{101}110\color{red}{111}000\ldots$$

Here I’ve alternated between black and red in order to make it easier to identify the individual words being concatenated.

As for (*ii*), for each $w\in\{0,1\}^*$ let $C(w)=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}C_n(w)$; this is a union of open sets, so it is open, and it contains every configuration that has $w$ as a substring.

- Show that each of the sets $C(w)$ is dense in $X$.
- Explain why there are only countably many of these sets $C(w)$.

The Baire category theorem will then tell you that $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}C(w)$ is dense in $X$, and it should be clear that $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}C(w)$ is precisely the set of transitive configurations.

**Added:** For (*iii*) let $c_0$ be the transitive composition shown above. For each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ be the composition

$$0^nc_0=\underbrace{00\ldots00}_nc_0\,,$$

and let $c_{-n}$ be the result of left-shifting $c_0$ $n$ places. For instance,

$$c_{-5}=\color{red}{1}10\color{red}{11}000\color{red}{001}010\color{red}{011}100\color{red}{101}110\color{red}{111}000\ldots\,,$$

where I’ve kept the colors to make it easier to match this up with $c_0$ as displayed above.

- Show that for each $w\in\{0,1\}^*$ and $n\in\Bbb N$ there is a $k\in\Bbb Z$ such that $c_k\in C_n(w)$. Conclude that $\{c_k:k\in\Bbb Z\}$ is dense in $X$.

Finally, for (*iv*) let $c$ be a composition in which some word $w$ occurs at only $n$ different positions. Does the word $w^{n+1}$ occur in $c$?

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I have added 2 more questions $(iii)$ and $(iv)$. Can you please help me out with them?

Comment: @JOJO: I’ve added some hints for the other two parts.